# Discovering version of MPI api for a Makefile or cmake

Tags: makefile, cmake, mpi, dependency-management

I have a code that has some mpi api-dependent bits:

```
#if MPIVERSION==1
...
#elif MPIVERSION==2
...
#endif
```

that switches between assuming MPI-1 and MPI-2.

Is there a good way to infer a good version -- particularly one that might go in the build system?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do what `configure` scripts usually do - try to compile and run a very simple test MPI code that consists of:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main (void)
{
    int version, subversion;
    MPI_Get_version(&version, &subversion);
    printf("%d.%d\n", version, subversion);
    return 0;
}
```

Compile this code with `mpicc` (or whatever compiler was specified) and run it (directly and not through `mpirun`) during code configuration time and you will both:

- know that the MPI compiler wrapper actually works
- get the supported MPI standard major and minor versions

You can do the same for Fortran projects.

You can also try to parse `mpi.h` directly and search for `MPI_VERSION` and `MPI_SUBVERSION` but you might run into some non-portability issues. Besides those macros are meant to be used for conditional compilation inside the C/C++ code.

Answer (score 1):

Use `MPI_VERSION` along with `MPI_SUBVERSION` if needed (i.e MPI 1.2 is `MPI_VERSION = 1` and 
`MPI_SUBVERSION = 2`).  Documentation [here](http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-20-html/node29.htm#Node29)

Comment: Thanks. I think you are saying we are using a nonstandard envvar ... however this is still something we set ourselves. I wasn't sure from the documents whether those variables represent something we can discover automatically ... something we can rely on to be in the environment. We have a seemingly fine MPI on our system but I see no such env var.

Comment: These aren't environment variables.  They are preprocessor definitions in C and constants in Fortran.

Comment: Your right, I guess what he is looking for is how to define in autoconf the version of MPI which is needed.